# jQuery table header alignment

Tags: jquery, css-tables

I am pretty new to, well, all web programming and would like to ask... In the following code, how do I align the rotated `<th>` fields so that the table looks proper, the fields are aligned, and not off the screen?

This is the rotation function I am using. (I just posted it to get rid of the errors, you really need to see the jsfiddle link to really know what I mean)

```
.r90 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
width: 1.25em;
line-height: 1ex;
font-family:verdana;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/michaela_elise/CFNHP/15/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `th` text in a `span` and try this:

```
.r90 span {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    font-family:verdana;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:80px;
    height:80px;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/RLLDL/)

---

If you want to set the `height` and `line-height` dynamically based on the longest text, you can use this function:

```
var maxSpanHeight = 0;
$(".r90 span").each(function(){
    if (maxSpanHeight < $(this).width())
        maxSpanHeight = $(this).width();
}).css({
    'height':maxSpanHeight,
    'line-height':maxSpanHeight+'px'
});
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/E42KZ/)

Comment: Thank you guys so much!! I am going to combine all three answers because the table headers will be inserted dynamically.

Comment: Followup... I understand how to get the column header width.  How do I dynamically set the class line-height and height?  the attr() function?

Answer (score 0):

thing is with transform is it doesnt really affect other styling.

if you want to align your table you will have to use javascript(or jQuery) to get the rotated cell's width (the width stays the same even though they are rotated) and adjust the table head row height accordingly

Comment: I now have it dynamically getting the largest width.  How do I go about making the columns thinner? As you will see in the following code, the 4th column is very wide.  http://jsfiddle.net/michaela_elise/CFNHP/

Comment: when an element is transformed, the only thing that changes is how you see it on the page. the space it occupies remains the same, therefore even though its rotated, its width is still the same and it affects the column width. id suggest setting thad `th` width smaller, and set `white-space:nowrap` so it wont wrap ur header text

Answer (score 0):

can you check the following: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/js96c/)

```
.r90 {
    height: 100px; width: 100px;          
             font-size: 16px;
             -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
             -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
             -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
             -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
             transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
```